# How do you bind api data that is represented as a url?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, axios

http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/

```
{
"count": 319,
"results": [
            {
              "name": "Acid Arrow",
              "url": "http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/1"
            },
```

"url": "http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/1"

```
{
"_id": "5bce91f95b7768e7920184d6",
"index": 1,
"name": "Acid Arrow",
"desc": [
"A shimmering green arrow streaks toward a target within range and bursts in a spray of acid. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 4d4 acid damage immediately and 2d4 acid damage at the end of its next turn. On a miss, the arrow splashes the target with acid for half as much of the initial damage and no damage at the end of its next turn."
],
"higher_level": [
"When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, the damage (both initial and later) increases by 1d4 for each slot level above 2nd."
],
"page": "phb 259",
"range": "90 feet",
```

```
const axios = require("axios");
    const url =
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://dnd5eapi.co/api/spells";

    axios
      .get(url)
        // .then(response => console.log(response.data.results))
      .then(res => {
        this.classes = res.data.results;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

```
<v-card v-for="spells in classes">
      <v-card-title>{{ spells.name }}</v-card-title>
      <p>{{ spells.url }}</p>
</v-card>
```

I'm using Vue to test this, but it's the basic idea that I'm having an issue with. The issue that I'm confused with is I'm trying to bind the data from the "url" to display additional data from URL. How would I reach the "url" endpoint, and display the data?

Comment: You have to make another request to the api, but you wouldn't want to do that for every result 600+ reqs, so add pagination and when you do get that second set you only want to do once so cache everything.

Comment: That's great advice I will implement that. My main issue is how do you reach out to the "url" endpoint? It's like a weird inception dilemma where I want to display data for each of my spells, but it just shows the URL.

Comment: The data is exposed through the url but you cannot display it without first making a request. For this case you need to make a new request to get the extra information from each spell. through this `url` property you can only display links or images ...  
In my opinion the backend needs to be tweaked to bring this data